# Defining a Cutoff Point in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm having some issues with defining my own cutoff point in R. I'm
looking to redefine numeric data (weight in grams) to a binomial variable (0
= less than 5000, 1 = more than 5000.)

I've seen other tutorials on how to do something similar, but they all seem
to define variables based on a cutoff point defined by R. How do I perform
this operation myself?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Do you mean something like: `as.numeric(x >= 5000)`?

Comment: If you want to use your discretized data in modeling (as a dependent or independent variable), I strongly suggest you look into the problems such discretizing can cause. A few links are here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47074/does-it-make-sense-to-cut-a-continuous-variable-to-intervals/

Comment: Discretizing the variable is throwing away information. I can't recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
data <-data.frame(matrix(sample(1000:30000,50,T),ncol=1))
names(data) <- "wt"
data$wt1 <- ifelse(data$wt < 5000, 0, 1)

head(data)
     wt wt1
1 3389   0
2 4349   0
3 6156   1
4 9174   1
5 2815   0
6 9086   1
```

You need to decide about values of 5000 gm (0 or 1)